# How do i make a loop that prints 6 elements of a list per line?

Tags: python, list, function

What the program is supposed to do is take a users input that generates a collatz sequence then prints out each item from the sequence with a tab between each number but after 6 elements from the list it prints on the next line and so on so forth and the last line (the remaining elements) do not need 6. The last part is it's supposed to find the largest number from the sequence.

I've got the sequence to generate and I can find the largest number, I just can't figure out how to do the spacing.

What I have tried:
(that first print just has to be there)

```
def display_sequence(sequence)
    print()
    for i in sequence:
        print(i, end = " \t")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than iterating over an increasing sequence of indices, iterate over a repeating cycle of 0, ..., 5. The `if` statement can be reduced to a conditional expression to select `'\t` or `'\n'` as the end character.

```
from itertools import cycle

for index, item in zip(cycle(range(1, 7)), sequence):
    print(item, end='\t' if item < 6 else '\n')
```

Or, iterate over the starting indices of each slice:

```
for s in range(0, len(sequence), 6):
    print('\t'.join(sequence[s:s+6]))
```

The documentation of the `itertools` modules also provides a recipe of iterating over the slices `sequence[0:6]`, `sequence[6:12]`, etc. directly.

Comment: Comprehension? `result = {i: k for i, k in enumerate(sequence, start=0)} print(result, end='\t' if result < 6 else '\n'`)

Comment: @Barb No list is being built here, so no.

Comment: I meant would it be more pythonic to use comprehension to do this

Comment: No, because list comprehensions are for creating lists, and the OP isn't creating a list.

Comment: It is dictionary comprehension. It saves you making `for` loops and is easier to read

Comment: For the last time: the OP is trying to print a series of strings, not build any other data structure. It is not pythonic to use a comprehension just for the side effects of the expression building a list or dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

i want to see what everyone else does but this is what i did:

```
def display_sequence(sequence):
    print()
    for index, item in enumerate(sequence):
        if (index + 1) % 6 == 0:
            print(item)
        else:
            print(item, end = " \t")
```

Comment: As a side note: If you're looking for suggestions on how to improve already-working code, there's https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ specifically for this ;)

Comment: oh, thanks for letting me know I'm just also wondering if this works for every case if that makes sense.

Comment: I think that comparison here should be inverted according to what stated in the question: `if (index + 1) % 6 != 0: print (item, end='\t')`. Then six numbers will be printed with tabs in between and in the last line we need to print newline

Answer (score 0):

A small for loop that doesn't require any conditionals:

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase as seq

step = 6
for i in range(0, len(seq), step):
    print(*seq[i:i+step], sep="\t", end="\n")

# a    b    c    d    e    f
# g    h    i    j    k    l
# m    n    o    p    q    r
# s    t    u    v    w    x
# y    z
```

As a function:

```py
def display_seq(seq, step=6):
    for i in range(0, len(seq), step):
        print(*seq[i:i+step], sep="\t", end="\n")
```